# Animate div in list, keep siblings static

Tags: jquery, css, hover, jquery-animate

I have a vertical list of divs and I'm animating each on hover.  I want the rest of them to stay in the same position while the selected one "grows" (I hate to say it, but think MacOS Launcher).  I know I could do it if I absolutely positioned each one using a JavaScript loop, but I'd like this to be as dynamic as possible.

Ideas?

HTML:

```
<div id="leftMenu">
    <div id="lmHome" class="lmSelected"><i class="icon-home icon-2x"></i></div>
    <div id="lmSearch"><i class="icon-search icon-2x"></i></div>
    <div id="lmFeed"><i class="icon-rss icon-2x"></i></div>
    <div id="lmPeople"><i class="icon-group icon-2x"></i></div>
    <div id="lmNew"><i class="icon-plus icon-2x"></i></div>
    <div id="Div2"><i class="icon-calendar icon-2x"></i></div>
    <div id="lmSettings"><i class="icon-cogs icon-2x"></i></div>
    <div id="Div1"><i class="icon-question icon-2x"></i></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#leftMenu { /* The container for the buttons on the left menu*/
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    height: auto;
}

#leftMenu div { /* The buttons on the left menu*/
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: visible;
}

#leftMenu div i {
    position: relative;
    top: 12px;
}

#leftMenu div:hover {
}

#leftMenu div:last-child {
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#leftMenu div').on('mouseenter', function () {
    var self = $(this);
    self.stop()
        .animate({ 'height': '+=10px' }, { duration: 100, queue: false })
        .animate({ 'width': '+=10px' }, { duration: 100, queue: false })
        .animate({ 'top': '-=5px' }, { duration: 100, queue: false })
});

$('#leftMenu div').on('mouseleave', function () {
    var self = $(this);
    self.stop()
        .animate({ 'height': '-=10px' }, { duration: 400, queue: false })
        .animate({ 'width': '-=10px' }, { duration: 400, queue: false })
        .animate({ 'top': '+=5px' }, { duration: 400, queue: false })
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/bttah/

Use the right tool for the job. JavaScript, while giving old browsers animation capabilities that were mind-blowing 2 or 3 years ago, is not intended for animation, so here I give you an example of how your animation can be achieved with 3 extra lines of CSS.

```
#leftMenu { /* The container for the buttons on the left menu*/
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    height: auto;
}

#leftMenu div { /* The buttons on the left menu*/
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: visible;
    background: #fff;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#leftMenu div i {
    position: relative;
    top: 12px;
}

#leftMenu div:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    transform: scale(2);
    z-index: 100;
}

#leftMenu div:last-child {
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, but how I would I keep the left side static?  Like if the menu is on the left edge of the screen, I don't want the left side of the button to move out of the screen bounds.

Comment: You can use [CSS transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) to move things without affecting siblings. I'll leave that up to you to discover :)

Comment: Well I assume it's transform-origin, but I cannot get it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/bttah/6/

Comment: Don't assume. it makes an ass out ... oh what the hell I'll just do it for you: http://jsfiddle.net/bttah/8

Comment: So if I adjust the scale I just have to guess on the transform?

Comment: You mentioned transform-origin, so you're half way there. My previous jsfiddle was hacky on purpose to allow you to figure this out for yourself, but it shows how to combine multiple transforms.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31209/discussion-between-greg-and-scott-beeson)

Answer (score 1):

It's the perfect case to use CSS transforms, `scale()` in this case.

Here's a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/LeBen/vYjNT/1/

There's [more options available](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) and you can also add some easing with [transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions).